# Highcharts gauge property

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I have this handy little gauge using highcharts js library, but I am unsure how to remove the "0" shown right in the middle.  It was not there until I updated to the latest highcharts api, how do I remove that, what property what it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a `dataLabel`.](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.dataLabels)

> Data labels for the gauge. For gauges, the data labels are enabled by default and shown in a bordered box below the point.

You can change it in the plotOptions config or the series config as I've done in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsxeJ/).

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        },
        dataLabels:{enabled:false} // <-- turn that off
    }]
```

[image]